# Swift3/Firebase Database : How can I get sub key of value?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase Database:

[image: Firebase Database]

Hello there! I'm using a firebase database like that picture. 
How should I code if i want to fetch a comment which is restourant1's subkey?

Here is my uploading comment function.

```
ref = Database.database().reference()
        let key = ref.child("comments").child(item.restourantName).childByAutoId().key
        let post = ["comment": commentTextField.text]
        let childUpdate = ["/comments/\(item.restourantName)/\(key)": post]
        ref.updateChildValues(childUpdate)
```

I've known how to use observe, but I want to print all the comments 
 on TableViewCell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just `observe` for child `restourant1`.

```
ref = Database.database().reference()

ref.child("comments").child("restourant1").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

    for comment in snapshot.children  {                           
        let snap = comment as! FIRDataSnapshot
        if let comm = snap.value as? [String:String] {
            print(snap.key)
            print(comm["comment"])
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks, it works :)
So how can I put this optional value into a String Array?

`var data:[String] = []
data.append(comm["comment"]!)`

Comment: Yes, this looks perfect. Also you can wrapped the optional using if let guard let